# Activity com desenho de fundo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Bom dia!

Amigos, estou precisando de uma luz para realizar o desenvolvimento de uma Activity com o seguinte layout, conforme abaixo.

[image: Imagem exemplo]

A área na cor laranja deve ser desenha programaticamente conforme tamanho da tela do device.

Na área em branco deve ser colocada uma Imagem View.

Minha dificuldade esta em como desenhar a área em laranja programaticamente não sei nem por onde começar.

Se alguém poder me ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672488/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-an-android-native-application-activity

Answer (score 0):

Use um .png sobre uma imagem. Para colocar uma imagem sobre  outra tu pode usar `RelativeLayout`. 
Outra forma é usar o Vector Drawables:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html
Tu pode criar as imagens em SVG e depois usar um site que converte as imagens para Vector Drawables, tipo esse site http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/